# How to print multiple multiline strings from a list onto the same line

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I have a list containing string patterns for digits 0-3. I am trying to print them onto the same line, so that print(digits[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfOaE.png)+col+digits[2]+col+digits[3]) prints '1 2 3' from the # pattern strings from the respective list index, but can only get the number patterns printed on their own.

```
# Create strings for each number 0-3 and store in digits list.
zero = '#'*3+'\n'+'#'+' '+'#'+'\n'+'#'+' '+'#'+'\n'+'#'+' '+'#'+'\n'+'#'*3
one = '#\n'.rjust(4)*6
two = '#'*3+'\n'+'#'.rjust(3)+'\n'+'#'*3+'\n'+'#'.ljust(3)+'\n'+'#'*3
three = '#'*3+'\n'+'#'.rjust(3)+'\n'+'#'*3+'\n'+'#'.rjust(3)+'\n'+'#'*3

digits = [zero, one, two, three]
col = '\n'.ljust(1)*6 # A divider column between each printed digit.

print(digits[1]+col+digits[2]+col+digits[3],end='')
```

[The result of the above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfOaE.png)

Comment: can you add an expected output?

Comment: Expected output should be the three strings printed on the same horizontal line, not vertical, separated by the 'col'. ie. the same characters as per the output url above, but on the same horizontal line: 1 2 3 (but printed as the digits in # patterns). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is by reversing the digits matrix, right now each index in digits list has the complete digit values but if we keep horizontal values at each index it will print properly.

think it would be better represented in code...https://repl.it/@pavanskipo/DirectTriangularSlash

```
# Digits replaced horizntally

digits_rev = [digits[0].split("\n"), 
              digits[1].split("\n"),
              digits[2].split("\n"),
              digits[3].split("\n")]

for i in range(0, len(digits)+1):
  print(digits_rev[0][i] + '\t' +
        digits_rev[1][i] + '\t' +
        digits_rev[2][i] + '\t' +
        digits_rev[3][i])
```

click on the link and hit run, let me know if it works